# Catch error produced by incorrect mongodb New ObjectId() and send error to client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling

I am purposely passing an incomplete id to New ObjectId() while using Mongodb with node.js.
As a result, I get the following error:

```
BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
```

I am catching the error in a try/catch. I can console.log the error. However, when I use res.send(error) to receive the error message in the client side(postman), I receive an empty object.
I would like to know what would be the proper technique to catch that particular error and send it to the client.
This is a  simplified version of my code:

```
try{
const userId = new ObjectId('6w8268bkdkw') //wrong Id
}
catch{
  res.send(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using try/catch correctly:

```
try{
const userId = new ObjectId('6w8268bkdkw') //wrong Id
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(error.name); // BSONTypeError
  console.log(error.message); // the message it will send
  console.log(error.stack); // the stack dumps
  res.status(500).send(error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks by usinng res.send(error.message) I can send error message to the client.

Comment: You should never send the entire error message to a client - its of no use having the entire stack. The client wold like to know a code, simple message (preferably a user readable description) that some data is entered incorrectly or incompletely. Also, sending a status 500 is not correct coding in this case - a simple data validation error. Status 500 is used for severe server errors which mostly cannot be reversed by the client.

Comment: @prasad_ Yes, we should not send the entire error. The answer here is generic to explain how to use catch with error and what an error object has. 500 code is generic when the server exactly doesn't know what happened and how to progress. check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500). You are right we should not send the entire stack and messages or error codes are sent to the client.

Comment: And, for validating the `ObjectId`, its not required to throw an error - use the available API method.

Answer (score 0):

In your route handler function you can code like this, for example:

```
app.get("/api/:id",  (req, res) => {

    const id = req.params.id

    if (!id || ObjectId.isValid(id) == false) {
        const msg = { message: "The id provided is not valid, " +  id };
        res.status(404).send(msg);
        return;
    }

    // code for a valid id goes here...

});
```